# SwiftUI: Why does .shadow not display .secondarySystemBackground as a colour?

Tags: swiftui, shadow

This does not display .secondarySystemBackground as a colour:

```
Rectangle().shadow(color:Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground), radius: 7)
```

However: other colours work just fine:

```
Rectangle().shadow(color: Color(UIColor.red), radius: 7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just difficult to see, because secondarySystemBackground is very close to systemBackground.

You can see it better if you choose a different background:

```swift
Rectangle()
    .foregroundColor(.blue)
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    .preferredColorScheme(.light)
    .shadow(color: Color(UIColor.secondarySystemBackground), radius: 7)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    .background(Color.black.ignoresSafeArea())
```